# how to mapbox-gl expressions unique ID style settings

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, deck.gl, kepler.gl

I have a question about what is wrong with the Mapbox-gl vector tile style configuration.

I want to express 5 colors uniquely for the ID column.

example Data structure

```
id : 0 => 2 data
id : 1 => 7 data
id : 2 => 10 data
...
```

The value of this ID is not known. Can I give a unique color by setting a column name?

The results I want to say above are red for ID 0, yellow for ID 1, and blue for ID 3. For example, I don't know if the value of the ID column is an integer or a string. I want to give unique color automatically.

Comment: The arrow means that there is multiple data for the same ID value.

Comment: I want to set the color automatically with the same ID with the Match or Case function. (Set color by ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have set ID in the data-side as feature's property so the style can get its ID as template string like `{ID}`.

You can use style expression as below:

```
somePaintProperty = [
    "case", // similar with switch ~ case
    ["==", ["get", "ID"], 0], // when the value of ID property equals to 0,
    "red", // then, colors red
    ["==", ["get", "ID"], 1],
    "yellow",
    ...
    "black", // else(default), black
]
```

Comment: very very Thanks.

but, this also requires you to enter a value to match.

We want to find the unique keys in the mapbox-gl function and set the colors.


  ** I think the function **



    `somePaintProperty = [
        "case", // or "unique-case, unique-some" Any function that finds a unique value 
        ["==", ["get", "ID"] ], // User must not enter a value,
        "red", // then, Automatic mapping if there is a unique value
        ["==", ["get", "ID"] ],
        "yellow",
        ...
        "black", // else(default), black
    ]`

Comment: I think layers' id are only unique. Features in layer would be unique but can't access to each as far as I know.